# is it possible to add locations in map created by gmapping?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By moving the LiDAR in whole building, the map was created and also show on rviz. now i want to add specific locations in the building. Lets say i want to add location "Faculty Office" in map showing on rviz. please guide me how is it possible? If not possible by gmapping then guide me another technique through which it may possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344587/is-it-possible-to-add-locations-in-map-created-by-gmapping?/) by [john_vector](https://answers.ros.org/users/51801/john_vector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-02-19**:\

> i want to add specific locations in the building

Can you be more specific please ? How an information like "Faculty Office" would be used by a program ? Do you mean something like if you give some coordinates you could get the name of the location pointed to ? That would require some post-processing to manually identify each location.

**Comment by [john_vector](https://answers.ros.org/users/51801/john_vector/) on 2020-02-19**:
yeah exactly. if you give some coordinates you could get the name of the location pointed to. how can do that. kindly guide me

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2020-02-19**:
I don't have examples or any procedure to follow but what you are looking for is called image segmentation (maybe even semantic SLAM). I believe `OpenCV` may have algorithms able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi john_vector. What i have come to understand is that you want to create a map which would serve the purpose of showing different locations on it. So i came through this link(below) which is doing similar thing. Hope it helps :D

http://wiki.ros.org/rrt_exploration/Tutorials/singleRobot

---

Originally posted by [Raza Jafri](https://answers.ros.org/users/57015/raza-jafri/) with karma: 16 on 2020-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0